# How to approach this

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$2^{33x-2} + 2^{11x+2} = 2^{22x+1} +1$

The question is to find the sum of all the solutions for $x$.

How does one approach these type of problems?
I tried to take $2^{11x}$ as $n$, but failed to solve this. Help me out please.

Comment: I think you are on the right path. Take $ 2^{11x}$as n, and write the equation in terms of n.

Comment: It's no further solvable. We are not allowed to use a calculator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by 4 to get cubic
$$  t^3 - 8  t^2 + 16  t  -4$$

The three roots of the cubic polynomial are all positive. If we call the correct $x$ values $a,b,c$ we find the product
$$  2^{11a} 2^{11b} 2^{11c} = 4 \; ,   $$
$$ 2^{11a+11b+11c} = 4 $$
$$  11(a+b+c) = 2 $$

[image]

Comment: Oh wow thanks got it

Comment: And now, the roots are?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  since the roots in the the form 2^11k, the roots of the cubic equation are bound to be positive. However the roots of our original equation may not be positive.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  We are required to find the sum sir. There's no need to find everyone of them. Just the sum

Comment: Ok, i misread this,then it is Vieta.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$(2^{11x})^3\cdot \frac{1}{4}+2^{11x}\cdot 4=(2^{11x})^2\cdot 2+1$$ and now substitute $$2^{11x}=t$$

Comment: I exactly did that. But to no use. It's no further solvable.

Comment: Try solving the equation $\frac{t^3}{4} -2t^2+4t -1 =0 $

Comment: It's impossible for me to solve that without a calculator.

Comment: Cardano's formulas should finish the problem.

Comment: As your task is "find the sum of the  solutions for $x$", you don't actually have to solve the cubic equation... @NightcoRohak

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Yes that's true. But how do I do that?

Comment: You can use the Cardano formulas

Comment: We are not supposed to do that. Because our teacher told us to do this by using simple Quadratic equations.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that there is no typo in your equation?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yeah I'm sure. This question was asked in IITJEE a few years ago. So I don't think there is any mistake because I copied the exact equation. Just checked again.

Comment: $2^{33x-2} + 2^{11x+2} = 2^{22x+1} +1\\$

Let $2^{11x}=m\\$

$2^{33x}2^{-2}+2^{11x}2^2-2^{22x}2^1=1\\$


$2^{(11x)3}2^{-2}+2^{11x}2^2-2^{(11x)2}2^1=1\\$

$m2^1+m2^2-m2^3=1\\$

$m(2+4-8)=1\\$

$-2m=1\\$

$m=-\frac{1}{2}\\$

Is it acceptable? or you can find any flaw?

Comment: See here a copy from Mathematica

Comment: Moreover we can find sum of solutions of cubic using $\frac{t^3}{4} -2t^2+4t -1 =0$

$t^3-8t^2+16t-4=0$

Sum of roots of this cubic is $8$. (Which is $-\frac{b}{a}$ )

Comment: @VineetKumar actually, the important thing is that the product of the roots is 4

Comment: But this doesn't help to find all roots